# Make CPLEX use the number of real not logical cores

Tags: cplex

I am optimizing a model with CPLEX. It is a bigger model so it takes a lot of computing time. I have a machine with 8 real cores which are organized in 16 virtual cores. With the parameter 'threads' it is possible to vary the number of threads. But i need further explanation about what's happening when I change the number of threads.

Will CPLEX use only the real 8 cores when I set `threads=8`? Or will it just be ran in 8 virtual cores so that there is no real benefit? How should I approach this to reduce calculation time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cplex will use 8 virtual cores, and it'll be up to the operating system to schedule those threads on 8 virtual cores. Given all these threads are heady loads, it is likely that the OS will schedule them on different physical cores, but it is not guaranteed. So setting threads to 8 will most likely help.

To guarantee that each of your 8 threads will run on different physical cores you can set the [cpumask](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/CPUmask.html) parameter. For example, on linux you'd set cpumask to 00ff to use 8 different physical cores. (On linux, if hyperthreading is enabled on a machine with n physical cores, the virtual cpus i and n+i are on the ith physical core, so the mask 00ff, which is binary 0000 0000 1111 1111, instructs cplex to use the first 8 virtual core which will be on different physical cores.)
BTW, if you are on linux then you can use the taskset command to achieve pretty much the same result.

Oh, and you still need to set threads. cpumask only limits which virtual cpus cplex will use, it does not change how many threads are used.